# Unable to make showDialog's background transparent

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dialog

I am trying to popup dialog while making http request, to accomplish this I have created function which show dialog on screen.

Here is my code.

```
class AppLoader {
  static Future<void> showLoadingDialog(BuildContext context, GlobalKey key) async {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (ctx) {
        return new WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async => false, 
          child: SimpleDialog(
            key: key,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
            children: <Widget>[
              Center( 
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Text('Please wait...', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                ],),
              )
            ],
          )
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

and calling it like below:

```
AppLoader.showLoadingDialog(context, _keyLoader);
```

And output is screen as below.

[image]

As you can see, at the center there is rectangular white background shaped box is showing. I want to remove that white background.

I also tried to set `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,` but it not working. It is looking more wired UI.
[image]

Just want to show loader and text of dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background color of SimpleDialog to transparent then add a background color with elevation like below,

```
new SimpleDialog(
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  elevation: 0.1,
  title: new Text('Do you like Flutter?'),
  children: <Widget>[
    Center(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          CircularProgressIndicator(),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Text('Please wait...', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
        ],
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```